# request off white site

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

Usually python request response return status code 403 because we aren't adding headers or cookies. **I can access off white site on browser with 200 status code with no error**, but I try to make a python request with the same IP, even I add headers and cookies, the response status code still be 403, how to fix it?

```
import requests

headers = {
    'authority': 'www.off---white.com',
    'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
    'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.36',
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'cross-site',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
    'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
    'referer': 'https://www.google.com/',
    'accept-language': 'zh-CN,zh;q=0.9,en;q=0.8'
}
cookies = {'__cfduid': 'dbb927011700e1a6654aed64e3be4d89d1601309837',
            '__cfruid': '32d3c294a468dbe5ef1254ad964f1b22e74873c4-1601309837',
            '_gcl_au': '1.1.1392211025.1601309842',
            '_ga': 'GA1.2.1255230454.1601309842',
            'ftr_ncd': '6',
            'csi': '6e63759b-06ec-4935-992c-8314d38d7b5f',
            '_fbp': 'fb.1.1601309842324.1927132723',
            '_gid': 'GA1.2.1195156588.1601430772',
            '__cf_bm': '1d3ee8501a7526ec4511271daa97a3abe3e2aa3d-1601442959-1800-Adp/amBrp/ik3AN8N6TVkmGnJxueqQpruqfjlyHVjfzVTvujiiblECkqiskgN7Nk5Nu3gY1SIU8NgfmhjrpD1U4XQoOu8LRNc497hvTX3iMTzdP7SWl//ZSWAzi8PTFX/DVel1hAVZalU7JvGVRU1P0=',
            'stc117572': 'env:1601442960%7C20201031051600%7C20200930054600%7C1%7C1070700:20210930051600|uid:1601309842023.408333243.605433.117572.996209845.72:20210930051600|srchist:1070700%3A1%3A20201029161722%7C1070701%3A1601314935%3A20201029174215%7C1070696%3A1601430770%3A20201031015250%7C1070700%3A1601442960%3A20201031051600:20210930051600|tsa:0:20200930054600',
            '_gat_UA-46560214-1': '1',
            'forterToken': 'ff55724e90dc415d9cf5c48aaf619737_1601442959727__UDF43_9ck',
            'ctx': '%7b%22u%22%3a5000001834387983%2c%22g%22%3a1%7d',
            'ss': 'MuCQNJgEH-qKki3_tpzJzabjzzUlGvhHfhgk8YgDvQAqGRl2oXBRvaFa1zD8wV28ger90jBfbuvAzfvsr9Asdj7Om64CnqaTMoRURGMjVJ_B_JBNLvvwqbRFCtrD7s3MKR6sjC_x65PfQLhCAwVJvvSKvezoaMjAoFIMx3xdJVCggTeO73bcOp9enDsu-a1H9YS6pF7c5cSFF5AwVcdtz6Zjtn3Ckv-rM2xxadTLI9c',
            '_gat': '1',
            '__cid': '67bef6ef-0888-44b4-a7ca-d970fe21ce9d-c11a7209b235a76b813a100e'
            }

response = requests.get('https://www.off---white.com/en-us/', headers=headers, cookies=cookies)
print(response.status_code)
```

Comment: @YashShah this has nothing to do with https, and 403 (as well as any other HTTP response) means that the connection is successful.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.off---white.com/en/-US
is responding with 403, even when accessed by a browser. I'm guessing it's because they arent available at the moment? their page just says "BACK SOON". If you run `print(response.text)` you should be able to see the same html as you would from a browser.

Comment: If you saw "BACK SOON" probably because your IP is banned on that site, I can access off white by browser with no error, but when I make a request on python like code show above will return a 403 status code, I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Weird, im in Norway. So it might be location based.

Answer (score 0):

Status code 403 means the IP address is ‘forbidden’ access; possibly due to being either blocked or not granted access to start.

Brief definition of status code 403:

> The request contained valid data and was understood by the server, but the server is refusing action.

To answer your question “How do I fix it?”  You can’t.  It’s up to the site administrator to grant access.

However, you might consider using a proxy (but likely unnecessary as you get a 200 response using a browser) or rotating user-agents, as it might be the UA which is being blocked. There are loads of web articles on this subject.

For more detail, here is a link to the Wiki article on [HTTP Status Codes](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes).

Comment: I know 403 cannot be fixed, I mean I can access by browsers with response status code 200, but I make python request with the same IP, response will return 403.

Comment: There is likely server-side filtering applied to web requests which auto-reject a request that looks / smells like a bot.  Into which category the python-request label occasionally falls.  Consider rotating proxies and user-agents.  Loads of web articles on the subject.